# Adding stripe pod is giving me Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: error

Tags: ios, xcode, stripe-payments, xcode-6.2, applepay

I am using Stripe/Apple pay to achieve a transaction.
The method I am using from Stripe.h:

```
[Stripe createTokenWithPayment:payment
                    completion:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error) 
{
    //my implementation
}]
```

What I am failing to do:

- Build the project for 32bit architecture.

What I have already tried:

1. Adding other linker flags.
2. Setting the Build Active Architecture Only to YES.
3. Setting the architectures arm64,armv7, armv7s.
4. Moving the foundation framework up.
5. Deleting and adding frameworks again.

```
Error :
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Stripe", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_StripeView)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

PS: StripeView is my different class.

Comment: Also tried deleting the derived data.